# Difference between creating azure function using HTTP triggers/generic webhooks?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created azure functions with "HTTP trigger" and "generic Webhooks" with Visual studio 2017.The only difference I found that both "triggers" can be triggered by HTTP request.

both functions have "HttpTrigger" as parameter.
so I am confused when should we use one over the other as both triggers allows us to run small piece of code in cloud.

How Is it different from one another ?

Answer (score 4):

An HttpTriggered function can respond to any HTTP verb you configure. However, a webhook only responds to POST and expects the payload to be JSON.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#responding-to-webhooks

> This restricts requests to only those using HTTP POST and with the
>   application/json content type.

Answer (score 2):

A '[Webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)' is a user defined callback that can be registered on a website in case you want to react to certain events.

For example something that is often done is responding to events in a gtihub repository, like when someone does a check-in or an issue is added. Typically you would want to trigger a build when a check-in happens. You can [register a callback/webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) on github which points to a url provided by you that reacts to the HTTP POST called by github.

Azure function can be [configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) to be triggered by a normal HTTP request or it can be setup as a webhook i.e. it will be called whenever a specific event on some website has occurred. Functions configured as webhooks will respond only to a HTTP POST. There are already built in values to set up an Azure Function as a github or Slack webhook.

If you are not reacting to an external event or cannot register a webhook in the event source just go with the HttpTrigger and explicitly invoke your function.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#webhooks), the webhooks only work with 1.x version of Azure functions runtime while if you are working with the newer runtime 2.x - it is recommended to use the HttpTrigger instead.

From the documentation,

> In version 1.x, webhook templates provide additional validation for
>   webhook payloads. In version 2.x, the base HTTP trigger still works
>   and is the recommended approach for webhooks.